# SQL Select column based on variable condition

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do this, in two different ways:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Parts
WHERE Column_ID = 2807
AND part_author = (case part_private = 'Y' THEN 'domain\username' ELSE part_author END)
```

And also this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_parts
WHERE Column_ID = 2807
  and part_author = IIF(part_private = 'Y','domain\username',part_author)
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to check each row as I select it to see if it is marked private.  If it is, then only select that row if the user logged into the application is the part author.  If part_private is 'N', then select it for everyone.

Hope that makes enough sense for someone to see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I don't know how to ask it any better than I did.  I'm hoping someone can look at it and "see" what it is I'm trying to do.  In the CASE version, it seems that CASE cannot accept checking a column for a value.  It wants just a value to evaluate.  In the IIF() version, I'm not even sure what is wrong.  It looks syntactically correct, but it complains that the "IIF Function requires three arguments", which I say it has.

Comment: To form it in a question: 

I need a query that returns all rows, except if part_private='Y'.  If part_private='Y' then I only want to return that row if the user is the author of that part (ie, part_author=[%=logged-in-user-name%])  User name being supplied as a variable in the code that is creating the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR is what you need here. There are two types of records to select. Those which are not private, adn those where the author matches.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Parts
WHERE Column_ID = 2807
AND (part_private='N' 
OR 'domain\username'=part_author)
```

Comment: Holy cow.  That totally worked.  I hadn't even thought of approaching it like that.  Very simple, direct and to the point.  Thanks.